# Deleting Profiles

Tags: support

I would like to delete all of my profiles.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I have found that this "site" is completely useless.  I see no simple way to delete all of my profiles.

Comment: Ask the team by clicking on the "contact us" link at the bottom of each page (like https://meta.security.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: You can do it *site by site* only as in the link given to you by Deer Hunter. However, it is sad you leave us. Personally, I used many websites before this and I abandoned them all as soon as I landed on this one, so I personally can have an other reason to leave this except *this site is completely useless*. Hope you change the mind before leaving us, all members are important and no question is stupid. Regards